# Python Coding style Wrapping Lines

Tags: python

As described on  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html :

*Wrap lines so that they don’t exceed 79 characters.*

Usualy i use breaklines on line 80, but sometimes i have functions that requires many arguments, as an example:

```
extractor.get_trigger_info(cur,con,env,family,iserver,version,login,password,prefix,proxyUser,proxyPass,proxyServer,triggerPage,triggerInfo)
```

So, what type of advice could be given for keep the guidelines on python coding Style ? what is the best practice for functions with many arguments ?

THanks in advance.

Comment: Needing lots of arguments it a bit of a code smell. Perhaps it's time to refactory?

Comment: Could you give me an example? Im starting to learn Python , and im using the link provided on the question to keep things right.

Comment: You could, for example, create a class that contains all this data and simply pass around class instances. Added bonus: Your class can check for invalid arguments by itself. I also suggest a space after each comma for good readability, but PEP8 doesn't explicitly recommend it (but from the examples at *Whitespace in Expressions and Statements* you can deduce it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definitive reference for questions like these is [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).  PEP 8 gives you the freedom to break pretty much anywhere you want (provided you break after a binary operator and use implied line-continuation inside parenthesis).  Whenever you break a line, typically the next line starts in the column after the opening parenthesis:

```
def func_with_lots_of_args(arg1, arg2, arg3,
                           arg4, arg5):
```

My personal style is to try to arrange things so that the stuff on each line after the break is roughly the same length.

```
def func(arg1, arg2, arg3,
         arg4, arg5, arg6,
         kwd='foobar'):
```

rather than:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, arg3,
         arg4, arg5, arg6, kwd='foobar'):
```

Although PEP8 doesn't really say you need to do it this way.

---

As a side note, if you have a function with that many positional arguments, you should probably reconsider your program design.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the reference for PEP 8. I will consider the redesign because most of the code doenst have classes, only functions.

Comment: @hochl -- Updated code according to your suggestion.  I go back and forth between whether I like that or not (but I know a lot of people do like it).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to:

1. keep your code clean under 2 automated tools: pyflakes and pep8.py (there are various text editor plugins for that)
2. choose method you think is the best and stick with that in whole project. if there is methodic already, stick to that one.